# Linked List Simple Code eexception handling error comes and program fails

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to implement very simple code of Linked List but unhandled exception error occurred. I want to access 2nd element data from first
I have an error in printing it it the visual studio. An exception handling error comes and program stops working.

Error is:
0

Unhandled exception at 0x00105485 in LinkedList.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

```
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;

};

int main() {
    Node *p = new Node();
    p->data = 10;
    p->next = NULL;

    Node *q = new Node();
    q->data = 9;
    q->next = NULL;
    //now print this
 p->next->data 
    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `p->next = NULL` and then trying to read `p->next->data`. Which means that you are trying to read data from `NULL`. If you want to create a linked list from your nodes, you need to link them yourself, I.E. do something like this:

```
Node *p = new Node();
p->data = 10;
p->next = NULL;

Node *q = new Node();
q->data = 9;
q->next = NULL;

p->next = q;  // Link the two nodes

//now print this
std::cout << p->next->data;
system("pause");
```